# How to display an image side by side with text in the center of a div?

Tags: html, css

I can center the image to the left of the text easily if it is not centered with a float.

**Image & text inline on the left:** https://jsfiddle.net/gc19qqqp/3/

However, with `text-align: center` I don't know how to do it.

How can I make it so that the image looks similar to how I have it in the first fiddle but with the text/image centered? (`text-align: center`)

**Need image & text to be inline here in the center:** https://jsfiddle.net/cL55pzLa/

Should look like this: [image: example]

```css
/* recall alert styling */
#recall-alert {
    background-color: #fefab1;
    color: #d10101;
    text-align: center;

    padding: 15px 0;
    margin: 5px 0;

    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;

}
#recall-alert img {
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 5px;

}

#recall-alert a {
    color: #98bcb0;
    font-style: italic;
}
#recall-alert a:visited {
    color: #98bcb0;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="recall-alert" class="">
    <img src="http://www.hospitalsafetyscore.org/media/image/hss-alert-icon.png" />
    <span>
        Recall from chicken of the sea effective July 2015<br />
        <a href="#">Click to Read More</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the contents in a new `div` element with `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` set.

([Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gc19qqqp/4/))

```html
<div id="recall-alert" class="">
    <div class="alert-inner">
        <img src="http://www.hospitalsafetyscore.org/media/image/hss-alert-icon.png" />
        <span>
            Recall from chicken of the sea effective July 2015<br />
            <a href="#">Click to Read More</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#recall-alert .alert-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: ah, I didn't know I had to add extra markup. Thanks dude

Answer (score 2):

I think this might help you:

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gc19qqqp/5/)

**No change** in your **HTML**

**CSS**

```
/* recall alert styling */

#recall-alert {
    display:block; /*Added*/
    text-align:center;  /*Added*/ 

    background-color: #fefab1;
    color: #d10101;
    /*text-align: left; REMOVED */

    padding: 15px 0;
    margin: 5px 0;

    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;

}
#recall-alert img {
    display:inline-block;  /*Added*/ 
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    /*float: left; REMOVED */
}
 /*Added span selector */
#recall-alert span {  
    display:inline-block;    
}

#recall-alert a {
    color: #98bcb0;
```

Comment: This is clever, but Tiny Giant's answer (https://jsfiddle.net/gc19qqqp/4/) aligns the top image with the top of the first line as opposed to your answer which aligns the bottom of the image with the first line. His better gives me the look I was going for. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/8pam3nqh/2/

Styles I changed:

```
#recall-alert {
    text-align: center;  /* Changed from 'left' */
}
#recall-alert img {
   /* float: left;*/
   vertical-align: top; /* Added */
}
/* Added */
#recall-alert div {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

I changed your inner `<span>` to a `<div>` but you can opt not to. In which case, you can change the last style above to have the selector `#recall-alert span`.

Comment: Thanks @AbrahamUribe for your suggestion. I have updated my answer.